How to disable extensions when attaching to running container?
I am working on optimizing the memory of a running container to make it scalable. On another window, I am using docker stats to monitor the memory usage.
However, whenever I click on "attach to running container", a new VS code window opens and automatically installs extensions in my container, of course, spiking the memory usage (and making every read unstable).
I tried looking online without finding a solution, how do I simply prevent the installation of any extensions when attaching to a running container? I read that it automatically uses devcontainer.json, is there a way to prevent its usage?
